# How to remove back stack fragment's menu items?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a fragment that I'm replacing with another, while also adding the transaction to the back stack. Both of my fragments provide menu items to the action bar using ActionBarSherlock. However, I'm having a problem -- in my second fragment, the action bar shows both the first fragment's and the second fragment's items; I only want the second one's items. Is there any way to achieve this?

(I'm also using the support library.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update the action bar icons, you can override onCreateOptionsMenu() in the activity to define which menu is used for the active fragment. Then call invalidateOptionsMenu() after replacing fragments to recreate the menu.

If you're only using the drop down menu, you can override onPrepareOptionsMenu() and add/remove items from the menu.

Comment: How do I define which menu to use? Is there some method to choose which fragments' `onCreateOptionsMenu` to call?

Comment: you will have to provide that logic. It will depend on your implementation. You can check which fragment is visible or track it with an instance variable.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm using the `onCreateOptionsMenu` _in_ my fragments, and from what I can tell, there's no way to selectively pick and choose which fragments' options menus I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you had a `ViewPager` in the first fragment with `getFragmentManager()` passed to a `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor. And then you tried to navigate to second fragment using the same `getFragmentManager()`.

If so then pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.